# Jquery hide/show based dynamic data click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to implement a tab system with jquery (Not paginate system), it will be working as like as carousole

this is the snippet:

```
<div class="tab">
    <p>Tab 1</p>
</div>

<div class="tab">
    <p>Tab 2</p>
</div>

<div class="tab">
    <p>Tab 3</p>
</div>

<div class="tab">
    <p>Tab 4</p>
</div>
```

there above can be as much data as possible that comes from backend, there not only 4 tabs.

### So I am trying to achieve, when page load, there will be the first two data/tab will be visible. when users click on the 2nd tab, there should 2nd tab and 3rd tab visible, so that user can click on 3rd tab to navigate 4th tab. like if if user click on 4th tab, there should be visible 4th and 5th tab. likewise, every next tab should act same.

---

For example,
when page loaded,

the web will show lie this below

```
tab 1 | tab 2
```

so if i click on `tab 2`

it should show like this:

```
tab 2 tab 3
```

and if then click on `tab 3`

it should show like this:

```
tab 3 tab 4
```

so if i click on `tab 4`

it should show

```
tab 4 tab 5
```

likewise, every next tab should behave sam way.

Can anyone please help me to get it done with jquery?

I just tried a lot but I failed in every attempt

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a pagination system?

Comment: No, I am trying to pagintae system

Comment: It will looks like careosole

Comment: yes, but if you imagine a carousel it's like having a pagination system where if you change tab the new data will be fetched from server and displayed

Comment: Pagination will bring data from backend eash request. you should nt feel it as pagination, coz, in each div tab, there will be some iamges and text,

Comment: It`s not recommended to load all data when page load and just navigate throw tabs with JS or JQ, you can load data from database with each click using Ajax for example and hide the previous tab (just hide don't delete it, so user can view it again without need to load it from DB).

Comment: No, coz, there will 10-30 data, not more than this, so it is not wise to click and fetch data from backend. i want to load it once only

Comment: Well if this is the case use a simple pagination library since you already have all data. Try with [this](https://pagination.js.org). Nevertheless @ahmed-tag-amer is right, loading all data it's a risk.

Comment: It is very cool feather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out: it will show next tab on every click. If you want reverse traversing also please let me know.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            const tabs = $("#tabs");
            // To show first two tabs
            $(tabs).children(".tab").slice(0, 2).show();
    
            $(".tab").click(function () {
              if ($(this).is(":first-child") || $(this).is(":last-child")) {
                return false;
              }
    
              // If you want to swtich tabs back
              if (!$(this).prev().is(":visible")) {
                $(this).next().css("display", "none");
                $(this).prev().css("display", "block");
                return;
              }
    
              $(this).prev().css("display", "none");
              $(this).next().css("display", "block");
            });
          });
```

```html
<html>
     <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     </head>
      <body>
        <style>
          .tab {
            display: none;
          }
        </style>
        <div id="tabs">
          <div class="tab">
            <p>Tab 1</p>
          </div>
    
          <div class="tab">
            <p>Tab 2</p>
          </div>
    
          <div class="tab">
            <p>Tab 3</p>
          </div>
    
          <div class="tab">
            <p>Tab 4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you are welcome @howrecepes. I have also added code to move back

Comment: GREAT SOLUTION. I LIKE THESE TYPES OF SOLUTIONS, VERY MINIMAL AND OPTIMIZED. THANKS